# ExceptionInInitializerError with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have seen a number of similar questions, but none of them seem to answer this. I keep getting `ExceptionInInitializerError` no matter what I try do:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;

import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
```

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate mockedRestTemplate;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {    
        fail("Not IMMM");
    }

}
```

I have also tried `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` but still the same error.

The stacktrace is as shown:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.ConditionalStackTraceFilter.<init>(ConditionalStackTraceFilter.java:17)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.filterStackTrace(MockitoException.java:41)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException.<init>(MockitoException.java:30)
    at org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MockitoConfigurationException.<init>(MockitoConfigurationException.java:18)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:12)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:11)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ReturnsEmptyValues.<init>(ReturnsEmptyValues.java:58)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ReturnsMoreEmptyValues.<init>(ReturnsMoreEmptyValues.java:51)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ReturnsSmartNulls.<init>(ReturnsSmartNulls.java:40)
    at org.mockito.Answers.<clinit>(Answers.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3320)
    at java.lang.Class.enumConstantDirectory(Class.java:3341)
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumValue(AnnotationParser.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:347)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:266)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1150)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1148)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:1139)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:207)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkField.getAnnotations(FrameworkField.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.addToAnnotationLists(TestClass.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.<init>(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:23)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.<init>(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.util.RunnerProvider.newInstance(RunnerProvider.java:39)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.create(RunnerFactory.java:28)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.<init>(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getStackTraceCleanerProvider(Plugins.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)
    ... 65 more
```

Comment: Your test class looks fine. You can even remove the annotation as long as you have `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`. Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: Could you show all imports and the exception stacktrace?

Comment: @kidney, added imports and stacktrace.

Comment: Have you tried without the `RunWith` annotation? You shouldn't really need it, since you are using the `MockitoAnnotations.init` method to init mocks. Also, Mockito version could play a role... Your code works fine on my machine with Mockito 2.28.2, JDK 8 and 12 and Junit 4.12...

Answer (score 2):

I Was experiencing the same issue. Fixed it by changing the dependency in the po.xml as follows. At first, it was mokito-all. changed it to mokito-core.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Changing Mockito-all to mockito-core worked for me.